# How can I map an object in order to change it?

Tags: reactjs, object

I need to map an object

```
obj={a:'',b:firstname,c:'',d:lastname}
```

while mapping if an element of an object does contain : '', i will return to to **null** so the result will be like that :

```
obj={a:null,b:firstname,c:null,d:lastname}.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of all the property names in the object, and then use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build up a new object where all properties with value `''` get the value `null` instead.

```js
const obj = { a: "", b: "foo", c: "", d: "bar" };

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = obj[key] === '' ? null : obj[key];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `for` `in`

```
var obj = {a:'',b:'firstname',c:'',d:'lastname'}
for(var key in obj){
    if(obj[key] === ""){
        obj[key] = null
    }
}
console.log(obj)
```